# Matched CSS on Weinre

Tags: android, css, debugging, weinre

I can't find all the CSS matched on my website while I debug using Weinre. I am opening my website from my Android device (Android browser):

http://192.168.0.159/website/

And then, on my desktop Chrome:

http://192.168.0.159:8080/client/#anonymous

I got it finally working when I stopped my antivirus and firewall, so I can hover the dom elements and I see them getting the blue layer on top of them (as the inspector does).

The problem is that I'm not getting my media query CSS supposedly matched to show on Weinre inspector.

I can't see any activity on the Network tab either.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

These actually sound like fairly standard limitations of weinre.  If you're working on a recent Android device, you may will find the built-in Android debugger works quite well.  More info here: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I think you are right and Weinre looks quite out of date.  However, there is no way to use a kind of Chrome Developer Tools with the Android Stock Browser. I just can't find it

Comment: The link I posted to the weinre docs, has a new section listing real debuggers that you can use with modern mobile devices.  Did you check the Android link there?  Here it is fer ya: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Comment: Hi Patrick. That allows to debug using Chrome. What I'm looking for is debugging Android native browser. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ah, so you're talking about the old browser - "Web Browser" - IIRC.  And you're on Android < 4.0, so can't run Chrome?  In that case, I think weinre may be your only option.  weinre can't handle media queries on CSS, so they won't show up in the applicable CSS rules.  The Network tab for weinre can only show XHRs, not other network requests for resources, etc.